# Cómo permitir solo correos que acaben con @gmail.com (PHP)

Tags: php

Este código sirve para añadir un punto (.) a una dirección de Gmail y así registrarse en un sitio varias veces con correos random derivados de la original.

El código funciona bien, pero funciona con cualquier dominio (ej: @casa.com)

Me gustaría que sólo funcione con `@gmail.com` y que si no acaba así, el script no genere los correos y muestre un `echo` de error dentro de un `<div>`. (probé esto en mi HTML) `<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com$">`

Pero prefiero que sea del lado del servidor y no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</textarea></div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="title">DOT MAILS GENERATOR</div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Gmail/E-mail Address *" autocomplete="off" required>
        <button name="send">GENERATE</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es una solición backend, se puede modificar el primer `if` de tu código poniendo un segundo condicional para verificar si el correo termina con @gmail.com:

```php
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']) and (substr($_POST['email'], -10) == '@gmail.com'))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    // ... más código 
} else {
    echo '<p>Error, el dominio debe ser @gmail.com</p>';
}

// resto del código
```

[Nota] En php 8 se puede usar [str_ends_with()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-ends-with.php)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó perfectamente!

Answer (score 1):

Sólo tienes que agregar un if() comparando si $domain es igual a "@gmail.com" o no, y generar los divs pertinentes según el caso.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    if (strtolower($domain) != "@gmail.com") {
        echo '<div>SORRY, ONLY FOR GMAIL DOMAIN!!!</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';

        foreach($res as $mcMails)
        {
            echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '</textarea></div>';
    }
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="title">DOT MAILS GENERATOR</div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Gmail/E-mail Address *" autocomplete="off" required>
        <button name="send">GENERATE</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo, su respuesta también me funcionó a la perfección!

Answer (score 0):

De verdad muchas gracias a todos! Basado en la respuesta de @aeportugal este es el resultado final:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if(isset($_POST['email']) and (substr($_POST['email'], -10) == '@gmail.com'))
{
    $mail = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
    $email = $mail[0];
    $domain = '@'.$mail[1];
    $email = ltrim($email);
    $domain = ltrim($domain);
    $email = rtrim($email);
    $domain = rtrim($domain);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $domain = stripslashes($domain);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $domain = htmlentities($domain);
    $res = addDOT($email);
    echo '<div class="box"><div class="title">Total: '.sizeof($res).'</div><textarea type="text">';
    foreach($res as $mcMails)
    {
        echo nl2br($mcMails.$domain).PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</textarea></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div>Error, el dominio debe ser @gmail.com</div>';
}

function addDOT($str){ 
    if(strlen($str) > 1)
    {
        $ca = preg_split("//",$str); 
        array_shift($ca); 
        array_pop($ca); 
        $head = array_shift($ca); 
        $res = addDOT(join('',$ca)); 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($res as $val)
        { 
          $result[] = $head . $val; 
          $result[] = $head . '.' .$val; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    } 
    return array($str); 
}
?>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="title">DOT MAILS GENERATOR</div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Gmail/E-mail Address *" autocomplete="off" required>
        <button name="send">GENERATE</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```